# Events sent via Google Analytics Hit Builder not showing up

Tags: api, google-analytics

I am looking to send hits to our Google Analytics account from our server-side REST application.   It seems this is possible by constructing a POST request based on the format at https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/

However, multiple attempts at sending test hits have failed.  I have tried sending tests from within Hit Builder as well as via cURL.  I've confirmed our TID (Tracking ID) is correct and the URL and parameters validate properly in Hit Builder.

Any tips appreciated!

Comment: p.s.   Hit Builder says each attempt was successful and the cURL tests also returned a HTTP 200.  But nothing shows up in the Real Time Events or Behaviour Events in Google Analytics

Comment: GA always returns 200 even when the payload was incorrect and hit builder will happily return success for events even when you omit the required category and action for an event, so that's not really helpful. Can you post your hit (with an anonymized UAID) ?

Comment: https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-123456-1&cid=477930332241&t=event&ec=video&ea=test&el=entry&ev=300

This is being sent using Postman as HTTP POST x-www-form-urlencoded

Here is the really strange thing:  I created a new property in our GA account and the event shows up.  The *only* difference is the -1 and -2 suffix in the TID.   

not sure if it matters but I suspect our existing GA property was a 'classic' whereas the new one I just created today is a 'universal'.  However, according to Google all accounts have been migrated to universal.

Comment: Anybody?  I get the same issue too...

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this information helps concerning the Google Analytics Measurement Protocol (validating hits)

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/validating-hits

I remain a little confused by this bit:

"Important: hits sent to the Measurement Protocol Validation Server will not show up in reports. They are for debugging only."

I guess besides the Reports, you can still see the Events getting fired off in real-time, they don't get reported/recorded, that's all.

Just some example usage for a Google Analytics account that I set up, (for a mobile app).  I first constructed an example Event-type hit.  Checked that it liked it.  And then fired it off to Google Analytics:

[image]

And then over in the Google Analytics account, navigate to Real-time > Events and take a look:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is probably quite late for your purpose given that the OP was made in 2016, but I'm posting so that it could help anyone else with the same question. Here's one likely scenario (happened to me):

You are sending hits to GA from a location that you set IP filtering for under GA property >> View Settings. In that case GA will not show these hits. If you are indeed firing the hits from a blocked IP, then for testing purposes, either try using a VPN, or else create a new Test-View with no IP filter and check if the event shows up in that GA view.

Answer (score 0):

A little late but I encountered with this issue and I had two elements blocking the event from the Master view. Events registered good on All data view so I had to check filter by flter on my Master view. I had Carlos SEO's filters implemented and turns out the ISP Provider Bots 2 filter leaves out your event hits.

The second thing blocking my event was the "Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders" checkbox on the view settings; I had it checked.

Hope this helps anyone who has the same issue :)